# Simplify Boolean Expression Given Truth Table

Tags: boolean-algebra

[Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZbYa.png)

I have the truth table above which gives the minterm expression

$$F = (\neg a \land \neg b \land c) \lor (\neg a \land b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land \neg b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land b \land c)$$

but I'm unsure how to simplify it using boolean algebra to prove it is the XOR of a, b, and c.

Comment: It is also the XOR of $a, b, c$.

Comment: Yes, I know that's the final solution, but I'm not sure how to get there in steps.

Comment: You can notice that there are an odd number of ones in each column where the expression evaluates as one.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have to prove it using boolean algebra not just by the definition of XOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $x \veebar y = (\neg x \land y) \lor (x \land \neg y)$.

Note that, by combining terms with $a$ and combining terms with $\neg a$:

$$\begin{align*}
F &= (\neg a \land \neg b \land c) \lor (\neg a \land b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land \neg b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land b \land c) \\
&= (\neg a \land (\neg b \land c)) \lor (\neg a \land (b \land \neg c)) \lor (a \land (\neg b \land \neg c)) \lor (a \land (b \land c)) \\
&= (\neg a \land ((\neg b \land c) \lor (b \land \neg c))) \lor (a \land ((\neg b \land \neg c) \lor (b \land c))) \\
&= (\neg a \land (b\veebar c)) \lor (a \land \neg((\neg b \land c) \lor (b \land \neg c))) \\
&= (\neg a \land (b\veebar c)) \lor (a \land \neg(b\veebar c)) \\
&= a \veebar (b \veebar c) = a \veebar b \veebar c
\end{align*}$$